# Over ride woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php file of woocommerce in custom theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to over ride construct function of woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php file in my custom theme. How could i override it?
Actually I have an issue of "No parent found" after update of my old woocommerce to latest woocommerce.
due to below changes of woocommerce:
old code of wc-product-variation.php ->line no:83:

```
if ( empty( $this->id ) ) {
   return;
  }
```

New Code of wc-product-variation.php ->line no:83:

```
if ( empty( $this->id ) ) {
   throw new Exception( sprintf( 'No parent product set for variation #%d', $this->variation_id ), 422 );
  }
```

Any help???
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overriding, you may use following code in your theme file to check whether product is simple or variable first and check it by following code:

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_id); 
if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
 //here is your code
} else {
 $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $product_id );
}
```

Comment: Right, I didn't notice about it and your instructions are satisfying with my code!!! Thanks!!!